# Bash and MongoDB: Whitespaces in Eval not working

Tags: javascript, bash, mongodb

In a bash script, this won't work with `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

```
#!/bin/bash
value="White Spaced String"
mongo --verbose localhost:27017/myDB --eval 'db.ips.update({"id":"id"}, { $push: { "key": {"key":"'$value'"}}})'
```

where as this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
value="NonWhiteSpacedString"
mongo --verbose localhost:27017/myDB --eval 'db.ips.update({"id":"id"}, { $push: { "key": {"key":"'$value'"}}})'
```

Any ideas ow to work around this? I tried:

`value="${value// /\\ }"` which will substitute whitespaces with \ escape signs and a whitespace. Yet, no success.

This does work, yet I want to preserve the whitespaces in my JSON in Mongo:

`value="${value// /_}"`

Comment: Your escapig is no working, you have `"` which appear to not be escaping right

Comment: ok changed script, updateing now

Comment: Changed Question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the `--eval` option needs to be a single bash word, so you need to avoid bash word-expanding `$value`. That means you need to put the expansion inside double-quotes:

```
mongo --verbose localhost:27017/myDB --eval \
  'db.ips.update({"id":"id"}, { $push: { "key": {"key":"'"$value"'"}}})'
                                                         ^      ^
```

That argument consists of a single-quoted segment, a double-quoted segment, and then a final single-quoted segment. The double quotes inside the single-quoted segments are, of course, ordinary characters.